# Foundation- returning an NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I want to return an NSMutableString in my Foundation program. However, I get the following error:

> warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion
>   returning 'NSMutableString *' from a function with result type 'int'

for the following code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSMutableString* result = @"testing";

    [pool drain];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your main function. As you can see from the declaration `int main()`, it returns an `int`. In fact, `main()` is only allowed to return an `int`, which indicates failure or success (generally 0 means success and any other number is a program-specific error code). You can't return anything else there — it's just part of the language. If you're trying to *print* the string, you can use `NSLog(@"%@", result)` or `printf("%s", [result UTF8String])`.

Comment: Thank you. Printf was exactly what I needed because it was able to be caught by applescript's do shell script verses NSLog!